# show image from folder to page using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css

I am trying to make image gallery for my website .
in my case i am showing thumbnail of all images and if we clicks
on the image it shows image in modal window .
there are 2 folders

1. Thumbs (consist thumbnail)
2. Full image (consist full image)

i have put the image with the same name ,as well i can do it by giving path of my images hard coded like this code

```
  <ul id="gallery">
      <li><a  href="http://ppplugins.com/demo/ppgallery/images/l_01.jpg" title="Title will be here"><img class="GalleryThumbnail" src="http://ppplugins.com/demo/ppgallery/images/s_01.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

But dont know how can we do it without giving value hard coded .
please help me .
like if i add more iages in that folders it must show the image on page .
checkout here 
1>`http://182.50.154.23/elweb//CheckImagesFromFolder.aspx`(trying to make it as 2nd link given below but not using source hard coded)
2>`http://182.50.154.23/elweb//Gallery.aspx` (required output)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, unfortunately your question is of poor quality and most users of this website will be unable to give you a good answer because of that. Please have a look at the short but effective FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and update your question accordingly. Good points to consider are: "What have you tried? Add a piece of your code. Which errors did you get?, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var thumbs = Directory.GetFiles("your thumbs directory");
        var images = Directory.GetFiles("your images directory");
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            var thumbname = thumbs.Where(x => x.Substring(2) == image.Substring(2));
        }
```

I'm not sure if it's what you want, but if the files are in two seperate folders it will take their paths.

You can also match thumb with image comparing their names.

Comment: no not working .. please checkout question i have make some improvement in that

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Where the files are located? Same server as application? If yes, what's the problem? If no, where they are? How you can access them?

Comment: the files are located in 2 folders and the folders are in root . 
the problem is that ..by using code behind i am able to get the thumbs of image but i want to show the thumbs and by clicking thumbs it must  show the full image in moodal popup as i did with hardcoded source .
i have mentioned the url in question

Answer (score 0):

Use Database to store image name and Path. use reapeter control to show image list.

Comment: href="~/FolderName/ImageName" so your bind to control is like :         <a href='<%# "~/FolderName/" + Eval("ImageName") %>'

Comment: can you please explain the method ...i am newbie so